# Does exists sense to call method of super?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, super

E.g. :

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB { 


public void run() {
  super.execute();
 ...................
```

Method execute exists only in ClassB.
Does it make sense to use:

```
super.execute();
```

may be enough:

```
execute();
```

?
Thanks.

Comment: In this case execute() is same super.execute(), however that may not always be the case and Child class can override the parent's method and in that case it helps to clearly tell compiler which method you're calling.

Comment: @anubhava: I should say "it helps to clearly tell *other readers*...." too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reasons:

1. **Predictability** (safety?) - if one day somebody implements `ClassA.execute()`, the code will work differently. This is also the case even is somebody subclasses `ClassA` and overrides `execute()`, leaving `ClassA` intact.
2. **Performance** - super call *may* be faster than virtual. `super` is implemented using `invokespecial` (single dispatch, just like `private` method), while ordinary call to non-private method uses double dispatch (virtual call). This is a weak advantage in modern JVMs.

Bottom line: if `ClassB.execute()` is `final`, using `super` has no sense.

Comment: +1, nice answer. And as always, profile the program before adjusting the code for performance reasons.

Answer (score 6):

Since the `execute()` method is not overridden in `ClassA`, `execute()` is **equivalent** to `super.execute()`.

I see absolutely no "documentational" benefit of highlighting the fact that the method is defined in the super class. Thus personally I would write `execute()` (unless there were strong reasons to call `super.execute()` if `ClassA` was ever modified to override `execute`).

Comment: This condition: Method execute exists only in ClassB.

Comment: Author mentioned that this method is not overridden, since it's located only in base class.

Answer (score 3):

No, simply call `execute()`. Since the **method is not overridden**, `super.execute()` would have the same result as `this.execute()`, which is the same as `execute()`.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok to call `super`.

If you want to ensure you are calling the parent class method, then use `super`. So if you introduce the method later in `ClassA`, code will not break.

By the contrary, if you want to call `execute` whatever it is... don't use `super`.

`super` reserved word exist normally to call to the overriden method from the overrider one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the java syntax this is correct. but when it comes to the real software engineering concepts this wont make any sense at all.I would suggest you to override run method in class B and then call the super class method inside that. After calling the supper class method you can construct you specific logic for the subclass. Its like you have some generic functionalities in the parent method and specific functionalities (in additions to what parent has) in sub class.